# AsyncTask onPostExecute causing crash

Tags: java, android

When apps installed, copy database work just fine. But when i tried to copy database in onUpgrade. the apps crashed even i left it empty in onPostExecute. But the database successfully copied and apps work just fine. Please help me.

LoginActivity

```
public class AsyncCopyDatabase extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    DatabaseHelper db;
    ProgressDialog progress;

    protected void onPreExecute(){
        super.onPreExecute();

        db = new DatabaseHelper(LoginActivity.this);

        progress = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
        progress.setMessage("Preparing data. Please wait..");
        progress.setCancelable(false);
        progress.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        //return null;
        try {
            db.createDatabase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }

        db.openDataBase();

        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        //Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        progress.dismiss();
    }

}
```

DatabaseHelper

```
public void CopyDataBaseFromAsset() throws IOException{

    InputStream in  = ctx.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);
    Log.e("sample", "Starting copying" );

    String outputFileName = DATABASE_PATH+DATABASE_NAME;
    File databaseFile = new File(DATABASE_PATH);
    // check if databases folder exists, if not create one and its subfolders
    if (!databaseFile.exists()){
        databaseFile.mkdir();
    }

    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outputFileName);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;


    while ((length = in.read(buffer))>0){
        out.write(buffer,0,length);
    }
    Log.e("sample", "Completed" );

    //db_delete();

    out.flush();
    out.close();
    in.close();

}
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (newVersion > oldVersion) {

        db.close();
        boolean b = ctx.deleteDatabase(DATABASE_NAME);
        if(b){
            try{
                CopyDataBaseFromAsset();
            }
            catch (IOException e){
                throw new Error("Error copying database");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What error you are getting in your logcat

Comment: try adding `super.onPostExecute(result)` as the first statement of `onPostExecute` method

Comment: still crash. 01-11 08:51:50.680 17629-17629/my.com.syabas.webgis E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity my.com.syabas.webgis.LoginActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{4227c680 V.E..... R......D 0,0-684,192} that was originally added here
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:383)

Comment: problem solved when i remove db.close(); thank you guys for your answers